# process local notification in background on ios 8 ( Swift 3 )

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, localnotification

I've been searching the forums but can't find a good answer for Swift 3.

I'm generating a local notification via `UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotifiction(nofication)`, but the **.background activationMode** doesn't seem to work. I understand that when user clicks this notification in this mode it should bring my app in .background state and execute my code without bringing my app in foreground.

Here is my code in the viewDidLoad() of a controller (it's a copy paste from a post):

```
let restartAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    restartAction.identifier = "xx"
    restartAction.isDestructive = false
    restartAction.title = "Restart"
    restartAction.activationMode = .background
    restartAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false


    let xAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    xAction.identifier = "xx1"
    xAction.isDestructive = false
    xAction.title = "Start"
    xAction.activationMode = .background
    xAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false

    let categoryIdentifier = "category.identifier"
    category.identifier = categoryIdentifier
    category.setActions([xAction,restartAction], for: .minimal)
    category.setActions([xAction, restartAction], for: .default)

    let categories = Set(arrayLiteral: category)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: categories)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)


    let localNotif = UILocalNotification()
    localNotif.alertBody = "testBody"
    localNotif.category = categoryIdentifier

    // Notification will be shown after 10 second (IMPORTANT: if you want to see notification you have to close or put app into background)
    localNotif.fireDate = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(20) as Date
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotif)
```

In the `Appdelegate` I have the following:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Local notification received 1")
    print (notification)
}
```

There are 2 problems with my code ( maybe related to one another ):

1. When taping the notification the app is brought in foreground and then my application(:didReceieve:) is called.
2. There are no option buttons attached to my notification. There should be 2 buttons which the user can click "Start" and "Restart"

What am I doing wrong?

---

OK, the above code is working but in ios 10 you have to pull the notification down for the options to appear. Not like the pictures where the buttons are in the notification box

Comment: The UILocalNotification class is deprecated in Swift 3.0 or later. You cannot instruct this class in Swift 3.0 or later. Therefore use the UNUserNotifactions class instead

Comment: OK, the above code is working but in ios 10 you have to pull the notification down for the options to appear. Not like the pictures where the  buttons are in the notification box